# Send alert when last case created is more than 5 days

Tags: apex, visual-workflow

I've a requirement where I need to send an alert when the last case created for each category (record type) is more than 5 days from today.
Example: For record type "A", the last record created was on June 5, 2023. So, I should be sending an alert for this record type.
I've created a Schedule Trigger Flow which runs at a particular interval and is sending an alert when it finds the last record for all the record types created was more than 5 days. How do I put a loop inside this to segregate the records according to the record type and send alerts for each record type.
This is how my Flow and the "Get Cases" node are looking now:
[image]
[image]
How do I segregate the records based on record types?
Please advise.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For the loop, first you have to get all the recordtypes:

- **Make a Get Records like this:**

[image: Get_Recordtypes] (Make sure to select the option to get all records)

- **Make a Loop on the resultant record types:**

[image: Flow]

- **In the loop, make another Get Records (Get_Latest_Case) that matches the Record type by Id and Sorts descending by Created Date. Choose the option to get only the first record. This gets the latest record:** [image: GetRecordsInLoop]
- **Make a formula called Days_Old:
  `TODAY() - DATEVALUE({!Get_Latest_Case.CreatedDate})`:**

[image: Days_Old_Formula]

- **Use a Decision element:**
  [image: Decision]

[image]

Comment: Hi Matt.Thanks so much for your response. It's really hard to believe that you did explain this flow at such a detail level. I cant thank you enough.
I see it's almost done from my end. However, I'm facing the following issue. Please let me know if you are aware of this:
Error element Send_Email_on_Case_not_been_created_from_last_5days (FlowActionCall).
parent object is wrong type for quickAction et4ae5__SendDefinition__c.et4ae5__Support_Request

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use a Marketing Cloud email action. My company has MC too, but I never use any of the actions that are part of their package. Try using the emailSimple action, which I believe is native to the standard SF platform.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Formula field with `RecordType.Name + "_" + Days from which case got created (that is, TOday() - CreatedDate)` . Use this field in flow to split on the String value and have this in your flow.